# How to run browser with extensions in GitLab using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, automated-tests

I'm a little bit confused with running Selenium tests in Gitlab. I need the browser to launch with the extension that my company uses to log in to the web resource being tested.

I tried options.add_extension, and it works well in local environment, but it seems that same method just doesn't work properly when tests are run by Gitlab pipeline. By the way, there is no any errors or exceptions, it's just the fact that authorization fails. Right now I use following code:

```
options = Options()
    if os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT") != 'local':
        options.add_extension("./extensions/extension_name.crx")
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")  # open Browser in maximized mode
        options.add_argument("disable-infobars")  # disabling infobars
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # applicable to windows os only
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # overcome limited resource problems
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Bypass OS security model
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    else:
        options.add_extension("./extensions/extension_name.crx")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

As you can see, there are two blocks: first is the failing, and the second is working well